# Upvoting without discretion

Tags: discussion, voting

For the past 24 hours at least, someone has been upvoting questions without discretion on ServerFault.  At first, I started to downvote the particularly heinous misappropriation.  At this point, I'm less willing to take the reputation hit.

Is there a remedy to this activity or is it simply a side effect of the design?

It's difficult to illustrate the activity for the purpose of discussion.  Nevertheless, I frequent the site and actively notice trends based on observation.

As of 5/23/2010 at 11:00AM EDT approximately over the past 24 hours:

- [Nearly a full page of the newest questions](https://serverfault.com/questions)

A bunch of current examples:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/144469/ubuntu-on-virtualbox-can-only-show-resolution-of-800-x-600-how-to-change-it
- https://serverfault.com/questions/144497/huawei-product-passwords
- https://serverfault.com/questions/144514/dd-wrt-and-squid-proxy
- https://serverfault.com/questions/144513/data-archiving-vs-not

It's ridiculous to continue listing.

Comment: Some examples please? And: upvoting bad posts, or upvoting a lot of good posts?

Comment: (See also [Vote Fraud and You](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/).)

Comment: That's an informative reference Arjan, thanks.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to address this current issue.  I've also edited to provide more details.

Comment: It's widely held to be a symptom of the Electorate badge.  There was a question/topic here about it, but I can't find it.  Some people even admitted that at the end of the day they use up all their leftover votes by opening up and upvoting random questions with +1 or more.  I hate that badge.

Comment: That thought crossed my mind as well.  It sounds like there's no moderator remedy, which is unfortunate.  It's increasing the noise ratio.  Ironically, I'm 52 votes from it but legitimately.

Comment: @Aarobot, could that be [Is the Electorate Badge Working?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37203/is-the-electorate-badge-working)? (The [quote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37203/is-the-electorate-badge-working/37206#37206) *I now go to Stack Overflow daily and expend my entire vote amount on questions. I don't vote on answers any more.* was not serious, if I understand correctly.)

Comment: @Arjan: That might have been it.  The question itself is about something slightly different but the answers do get into a lot of what I mentioned.

Comment: Keep in mind, you shouldn't be downvoting unless the questions legitimately deserve downvotes. Just because someone upvoted them unreasonably, doesn't mean you should downvote them unreasonably.

Comment: They don't deserve > 0.  >0 indicates better than the average.

Comment: @Warner: one of the classic problems with question voting. Is the question before you 'what score does this question deserve?' or 'do I like it enough to add +1?'

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a "classic problem" as much as it's a flaw that should be addressed.  Thankfully, the person doing it appears to have stopped.  However, earlier today nearly every question was voted at least +1.

Answer (score 1):

This was probably an effect of the [electorate badge](https://serverfault.com/badges/75/electorate) as people tried to meet the 25% votes on questions requirement.